# return json object list from spring mvc controller

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I want to return json object list from spring controller and use it in view but it returns empty list!
I can not understand the problem.
I create activities objects in minutesController and return it as json.But I can't get it in form using jquery.
But I can see correct result in browser when I try localhost:8080/FitnessTracker5/activities.json.
My server is glassfish

addMinutes.jsp

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Add Minutes Page</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/WEB-INF/pages/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
                function(){
                 $.getJSON('localhost:8080/FitnessTracker5/activities.json' , {

                    ajax:'true'
                  }
                  ,
                  function(data){
                    var html = '<option value="">please select one--</option>'
                    var len = data.length;

                    for(var i=0 ; i<len ;i++){
                      html += '<option value="' + data[i].desc + '">'
                      +data[i].desc+ '</option>' ;
                    }
                    html +='</option>';
                  $('#activities').html(html);

                  });
                });

      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Add Minutes Excersisedddd:</h1>


    Language:<a href="?language=en">English</a> | <a href="?language=fa">Persian</a>
    <form:form commandName="exercise">

      <table>
        <tr>

          <td><h1><spring:message code="goal.text"/> </h1> </td>
          <td> <form:input path="minutes"/></td>
          <td>
            <form:select  id="activities" path="activity"></form:select>
          </td>

        </tr>


      </table>
    </form:form>



    </body>
    </html>
```

activiity.java

```
public class Activity {
    private String desc ;
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }


}
```

MinutesController.java
@Controller

```
public class MinutesController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addMinutes")
    public String addMinutes(@ModelAttribute("exercise") Exercise exercise){
        System.out.println("exercise" + exercise.getMinutes());
        System.out.println("exerciseeeee" + exercise.getActivity());
        return "addMinutes" ;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/activities" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Activity> findAllActivities(){
        System.out.print("ACCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCc");
    List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<Activity>();

        Activity run = new Activity();
        run.setDesc("Run");
        activities.add(run) ;

        Activity bike = new Activity();
        bike  .setDesc("Bike");
        activities.add(bike) ;

        Activity swim = new Activity();
        swim.setDesc("Swim");
        activities.add(swim) ;

        return activities;


    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value ="/test")
    public @ResponseBody Activity getMovie( ){

        Activity activity =     new Activity();
        activity.setDesc("aaaaa");
        return activity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using '.json' in your ajax call??

Comment: Have you tried a breakpoint in your Javascript? What is the value of "data" in your ajax callback?

Comment: @marthursson it seems it can not get "jquery-3.1.0.js"! I checked chrome console and it has error...Should I do something else to add it?

Comment: @AbdullahWasi I removed it but it is not problem

Comment: @marthursson please help me...how can I add jquery correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment above it appears the problem is that JQuery cannot be loaded, which is probably due to a misconfigured dispatcher servlet. You might try accessing jquery from the CDN instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to serve jquery from your application you should google for "serve static resources Spring MVC" :)

And add **`http://`** to `url`.

```
 $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/FitnessTracker5/activities.json' , {
```

Comment: Thank You...But now I get this erro in chrome :XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/FitnessTracker5/activities.json?ajax=true. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-..........and yet empty list in firefox without error

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RestController` instead `@Controller`.

Comment: Thank's But I understood the problem is loading jqueru..I see error in chrome console in the line that is adding jquery...Can you help me ?

Comment: not related to the overall answer, but you need to also annotate the method with @ResponseBody to set controller to avoid looking at a jsp page.